# Unable to view property window properly in Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am facing trouble in viewing project property windows with correct alignment. I am attaching the screenshot of the issue. The issue was not present till yesterday. Facing this issue from today morning. please help me to resolve this issue.

[image: Screenshot of UI visible in visual studio 2012 for property window.]

Comment: Try installing Visual Studio 2019? Any reason why you're clinging onto such an ancient version?

Answer (score 0):

You can try closing all VS instances & restart project with Admin/as it is. This doesn't seem to be any setting/setup related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. I just restarted my laptop.